# Confusion regarding designing stack

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I had to design a stack such that along with regular operations such as `pop`, `push`, `isempty`, `isfull`, it also supports a function `get_min()` which returns the `minimum` element in the stack. All operations must be in `O(1)`.

I used a `linked list` as a stack. And in each node of the linked list I added a special field `min` to store the minimum value in the stack. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
    int data, min;
    struct node *next;
}node;

bool isempty(node *head)
{
    return !head;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<"-->";
        head=head->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int get_min(node *head)
{
    return head->min;
}

int peek(node *head)
{
    if(isempty(head))
        return INT_MIN;

    return head->data;
}

void push(node **head_ref, int data)
{
    node *new_node;
    new_node=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    new_node->data=data;
    if((*head_ref)==NULL || data <= get_min((*head_ref)))
    {
        new_node->min=data;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->min=(*head_ref)->min;
    }

    new_node->next=(*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)=new_node;
}



int pop(node **head_ref)
{
    if(isempty((*head_ref)))
        return INT_MIN;

    int c=(*head_ref)->data;
    node *temp=(*head_ref);

    (*head_ref)=(*head_ref)->next;
    free(temp);
    return c;
}




int main()
{
    node *head=NULL;
    push(&head, 3);
    push(&head, 0);
    push(&head, 1);

    display(head);

    cout<<get_min(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to ask if I am violating any stack properties by using the above method, or is it a correct way to design a stack?

Comment: Well, in c++ you already can use `std::stack` based on `std::list`. Also if you want to improve working code, you should better ask such at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AmiTavory, they are absolutely possible. O(1) for push, pop and min.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I dont want to use STL, neither do I want to improve it. I would just like to know if its a correct way to design a stack.

Comment: The correct way to design would be where `stack` is a template class and you create a stack object and push elements on it, and execute methods on the object.

Comment: @AmiTavory If you read the above code you would see that each of them is performed in O(1). My question is have I designed the stack properly or violated any of its properties.

Comment: @shiva A doubly linked list would be more appropriate fro your requirements IMO.

Comment: For example http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-and-implement-special-stack-data-structure/

Comment: If your structure is intended as stack of `int`, it's fine by me.

Comment: @serhiyb Thats exactly where the question came from.

Comment: I know there can be other ways to design a stack which are more efficient, but I want to know if this design violates any of the stack principles.

Comment: The only C++ in this code is the use of `std::cin`. Aside from that, this is straight C, which is to say, badly designed C++.

Comment: Since this is C++, you don't need `typedef struct`.

Comment: @shiva: Some concrete examples about what Pete says. In C++ you don't need to `typedef` a `struct` name. In C++ you don't usually use a pointer to implement pass-by-reference, but just a reference (thus `**` in this code would be `*&` in more conventional C++ code), which can't be null. In C++ you don't normally use `malloc` but `new`-expressions, or standard library containers.

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you placed spaces around operators, such as `cout << head->data << "-->";`

Comment: In my testing, it appears to be correct, and meet the requirements. Why does it have a default value for some illegal operations on an empty stack, but not others? What is "isfull"? Of course, I'd prefer a simple class interface and ... other irrelevant stuff.

Comment: What if you `pop` the minimum value?  Your code doesn't appear to correctly update the minimum in that case.

Comment: @KennyOstrom 'isfull' is function to check if stack has overflowed, its not relevant in my case.

Comment: @aschepler Can you provide a test case in which the program would give incorrect output?

Answer (score 0):

Its correct only but my suggestion is that instead of storing the minimum element with each entry just create another stack & store the minimum element there .

Now during PUSH operation just compare new element with top element in min array 
if it is minimum or equal just insert this into new stack .

while doing POP operation just check the element which you popping whether it is same as the top element in min stack . If yes the POP the element from  min stack also along with original stack .

This will help save our memory .

This question has been asked to my in Intern interview at CarWaly